# Cloud Functions for Firebase: How to get the value of the data that was deleted

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I add a cloud function responding to a delete event, like this one:

`exports.onDeleteSector = functions.database.ref('/sectores/{idSector}').onDelete((event) =>`

I can get the key to the sector being deleted in `event.params.idSector` proving the trigger works, however, `event.data.val()` returns null.

The deleted record contains the references to the children to be deleted.  How can I get those before the parent is gone?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

`event.data.val()` returns null, because that's the current value of the database at the time of the trigger.  For all kinds of database triggers, this is going to be the case.  For onDelete, this will always be null.

If you want to see what was *previously* at that location, before the event happened, take a look at `event.data.previous.val()`.  Also see the docs for [DeltaSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot), which is the data type for `event.data`.

Comment: No longer exists. No sure how we can do this with DataSnapshot anymore.

Comment: @OliverDixon The API changed in version 1.0.  Read this to find out what changed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: It would be great if you can update the answer for v1. @DougStevenson

Answer (score 2):

The value of the entry being deleted is available at:

```
event.data.previous.val()
```

Answer (score 2):

Current way of getting the deleted data from `onDelete` trigger is like this:

```js
exports.userDeleted = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userId}")
  .onDelete((snapshot) => {
    const original = snapshot.data();
    // original contains the deleted data
  });
```